# как передать двумерный массив из array.cpp

Tags: c++, массивы

Есть два файла
Не считая хэйдера array.h , в ней только одна строчка:

int randoming();

array.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctime>

#include "array.h"

int randoming()
{
    float a[10][10]; int i,j;
    srand(time(0));

    for(j=0; j< 10;j++){ //строки
        for(i=0;i < 10;i++){ //столбцы
            a[i][j] = 1-((rand()%100000)*0.00001); //мутим случайные числа

            if (a[i][j]<=0.5 && a[i][j]>=0.01){ //задаем ограничения
                std::cout << a[i][j] << "   ";
            }
            else
               i--; //если не выполнены ограничения мутим рандомное число заново для этого элемента
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;             //новая строка
    }
    return 0;
}
```

ai.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include "array.h"
using namespace std;

float random(float i){
    return randoming();
}

int main(void)
{
    float i;
    random(i);

    return 0;
}
```

Только не говорите про лишние хэйдеры - поменяю. 
Как передать массив из array.cpp в ai.cpp, который вы можете вывести на экран, скомпилировав программу? 
И как соответственно получить его? 
Есть предложения?

Comment: Массив в таком виде как сейчас никак не передать, он существует только внутри функции  - это локальная переменная внутри функции, после того как функция отработает - массива уженет

Comment: Попробуйте использовать `std::vector< std::vector<int> >` вместо массива, передавать его в функцию randoming по ссылке(не по указателю, то есть вот так: `std::vector< std::vector<int> >&`), внутри функции randoming очищать и заново заполнять, а потом уже в функции random с ним работать

Comment: Да, есть предложения: НЕ передавать массив из `array.cpp` в `ai.cpp`. Наоборот, передавать массив из `ai.cpp` в `array.cpp` через параметры функции `randoming()`, а в функции этот массив просто заполнять.

Comment: Кстати, чего вы пытались добиться использовав `continue` в качестве последнего стейтмента в теле цикла? Зачем вы туда вписали этот `continue`?

Comment: не могу понять как отметить ответ как решение.

Comment: continue я указал, потому что использовал i--; Но я тоже посчитал его лишним и удалил у себя